# vertexes in directed graph returning null

Tags: java

I am having an issue adding vertexes to a directed graph in java. the vertexe's label has been renamed cityNum and the vertex class has setters and getters for the components of a city. my code iterated through a file containing the information, creates a new vertex, sets all the fields, then adds it to the graph. however newMap.addVertex(cityNum); calls the addVertex method of the directedGraph class and creates a vertex in that method and all the fields return null. any advice would be appreciated

code for creating new vertex in driver program

```
Vertex<Integer> newVertex = new Vertex<Integer>(cityNum);
newVertex.setCityCode(cityCode);
newVertex.setCityName(cityName);
newVertex.setPopulation(population);
newVertex.setElevation(elevation);
newMap.addVertex(cityNum);
```

addVertex method in DirectedGraph

```
public boolean addVertex(T cityNum)
{
    VertexInterface<T> addOutcome = vertices.put(cityNum, new 
    Vertex<T>(cityNum));
    return addOutcome == null;
}
```

vertex class

```
public class Vertex<T> implements VertexInterface<T>
{
    private T cityNum;
    int population, elevation;
    private String cityCode, cityName;
    private ListWithListIteratorInterface<Edge> edgeList; 
    private boolean visited;                              
    private VertexInterface<T> previousVertex;            
    private double cost;

public Vertex(T cityNum)
{
    cityNum = this.cityNum;
    edgeList = new ArrayListWithListIterator<>();
    visited = false;
    previousVertex = null;
    cost = 0;
}

@Override
public T getCityNum()
{
    return cityNum;
}

public void setCityCode(String cityCode)
{
        cityCode = this.cityCode;
}
public String getCityCode()
{
        return cityCode;
}

public void setCityName(String cityName)
{
        cityName = this.cityName;
}
public String getCityName()
{
        return cityName;
}

public void setPopulation(int population)
{
        population = this.population;
}
public int getPopulation()
{
        return population;
}

public void setElevation(int elevation)
{
        elevation = this.elevation;
}
public int getElevation()
{
        return elevation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating *newVertex* for nothing:

```
Vertex<Integer> newVertex = new Vertex<Integer>(cityNum);
newVertex.setCityCode(cityCode);
newVertex.setCityName(cityName);
newVertex.setPopulation(population);
newVertex.setElevation(elevation);
newMap.addVertex(cityNum);
```

In *addVertex()* you just creating another, empty Vertex.